# Can be thought of as [verb]+ing ... What's the grammar and use?

Tags: conjunctions, clauses, as

Consider this example:

> Subjectivity detection or ranking at the document level **can be thought
>   of as** having its roots in studies in genre classification.

I don't get what is the type of clause after `thought of as`, and what meaning this structure is trying to convey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: It means "It's possible for us to think of *subjectivity detection or ranking at the document level* that it has its roots in studies in genre classification."

---

Let's dissect the sentence:

> *Subjectivity detection or ranking at the document level **can be thought of as having** its roots in studies in genre classification.*

1. Let's replace the subject (*Subjectivity detection or ranking at the document level*) with X to make the structure of the sentence clearer.

   > *X **can be thought of as having** its roots in studies in genre classification.*
2. Let's turn it into the active voice:

   > *We can think of X **as having** its roots in studies in genre classification.*
3. To get to the meaning, let's ask ourselves:

   > *We can think of X **as having** its roots in studies in genre classification.*
   >   *We can think of X **as what**?*
   >   ***As having*** its roots in studies in genre classification.
   >   (= (It's possible for us to think that) X has its roots in studies in genre classification.)

According to Macmillan, ***[as being](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/as)*** is:

> used for saying that someone or something is considered or described in a particular way 
>   [...]
>   **as being/having**: *Madeira is described as having the best climate in the world*

There are many words that work like this, i.e. it's followed by a verb in the *-ing* form. The common ones besides *as* are *without* and *instead of*. For example,

> *He left **without saying** anything.*
>   *We decide to give him another chance **instead of failing** him for not completing the assignment.*